# Taking in RTSP stream, converting it to fragmented mp4 using ffmpeg before broadcasting to connected clients through web socket

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, rtsp, media-source

I am taking in a live RTSP stream and converting it to fragmented mp4 using ffmpeg before re-distributing it to connected clients via a websocket. The clients will then play it using a normal web browser such as Chrome with Media Source Extensions. Most of the time, the code will work as intended but there will be occasions when the process of parsing the chunks emitted from the ffmpeg stdout will run into some issues. ***When everything is working well***, each chunk of data emitted from ffmpeg will be parsed, sliced and regrouped into either a Initialisation Segment (made up of a FYTP box and a MOOV box) OR a Media Segment (made up of a MOOF box and a MDAT box). The key steps involved are:

1. Every byte of data coming out from will first be pushed into an array.
2. Next, I will try to locate the box headers ('FYTP', 'MOOV', 'MOOF', 'MDAT') in the data.
3. After the box headers are located, I will look for the length of each corresponding box (which resides in the first 32 bytes of each box) to locate the start and end of each box.
4. With the box's length, I will then parse the array to filter out the data.
5. Once the entire segment is filtered out, I will send it to all connected clients. For 'FYTP and 'MOOV', they will only be sent once to each client. For 'MOOF' AND 'MDAT', this will be a continuous process for as long as the client(s) are connected.

However, ***when things are not working well***, my code will for some unknown reason be unable to slice the segments correctly. During the debugging process, I will notice that the problem will start first with a segment having sliced a few extra bytes more than it should have at the end. This problem will then quickly escalate and the next few segments will go totally haywire.

My suspicion is that this problem has less to do with my code than from the ffmpeg output. Has anyone faced similar problem before? The following is my code. Any help on this will be much appreciated! Thank you.

```
const WebSocket = require("ws");
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const rtspUrl = "rtsp://localhost:8554/mystream";
const fs = require('fs');
const outputFile = fs.createWriteStream('ffmpeg_output.bin');
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 4001 });

var buf_chunks_string_holder_array = [];
var initialization_segment_ready_flag = false;
var initialization_segment_to_send = [];
var buffered_media_segment_ready_flag = false;
var buffered_media_segment_to_send = [];
var segment_end_index = { "box_type": "nil", "end_index": 0 };
var next_segment_counter = 0;
var processing_counter_queue = []
var moof_counter = 0;
var mdat_counter = 0;
var checker = '';

wss.on("connection", (ws) => {
    console.log("Client connected");
  if (initialization_segment_ready_flag == true) {
    wss.clients.forEach(client => {
      client.send(new Uint8Array(initialization_segment_to_send).buffer);
    })
  }
  if (buffered_media_segment_ready_flag == true) {
    wss.clients.forEach(client => {
      client.send(new Uint8Array(buffered_media_segment_to_send.buffer));
    })
  }

  ws.on("close", () => {
    console.log("Client disconnected");
  });

  ws.addEventListener("error", (error) => {
    console.error("WebSocket error:", error);
  });

});

const ffmpeg = spawn("ffmpeg", [
  "-rtsp_transport",
  "tcp",
  "-i",
  rtspUrl,
  "-g",
  "10",
  "-bufsize", 
  "50k",
  "-preset",
  "ultrafast",
  "-tune",
  "zerolatency",
  "-c:v",
  "libx264",
  "-c:a",
  "aac",
  '-f',
  'mp4',
  '-movflags',
  'frag_keyframe+empty_moov+default_base_moof',
  '-min_frag_duration',
  '50000',   
  "pipe:1",
]);

function decToHex(dec) {
  return dec.toString(16).padStart(2,'0').toUpperCase();
}

function hexToDec(hex) {
  return parseInt(hex, 16);
}

//This is where the parsing and calculating of the length of each box will take place.
ffmpeg.stdout.on('data', (chunk) => {
  outputFile.write(chunk);
  for (var i=0; i < chunk.length; i ++){
    buf_chunks_string_holder_array.push(chunk[i]);
    checker += decToHex(chunk[i]);
    if(checker.length == 16){
      if (checker.slice(-8) === '66747970'){
        let box_size_string = checker.slice(-16, -8);
        let num_bytes = hexToDec(box_size_string);
        next_segment_counter += num_bytes;
      }
      else if(checker.slice(-8) === '6D6F6F76'){
        let box_size_string = checker.slice(-16, -8);
        let num_bytes = hexToDec(box_size_string);
        next_segment_counter += num_bytes;
        segment_end_index = { "box_type": "ftyp&moov", "end_index": next_segment_counter };
        processing_counter_queue.push(segment_end_index);
        next_segment_counter = 0;
      }
      else if(checker.slice(-8) === '6D6F6F66'){
        let box_size_string = checker.slice(-16, -8);
        let num_bytes = hexToDec(box_size_string);
        next_segment_counter += num_bytes;
        moof_counter ++;      
      }
      else if(checker.slice(-8) === '6D646174'){
        let box_size_string = checker.slice(-16, -8);
        let num_bytes = hexToDec(box_size_string);
        next_segment_counter += num_bytes;
        segment_end_index = { "box_type": "moof&mdat", "end_index": next_segment_counter };
        processing_counter_queue.push(segment_end_index);
        next_segment_counter = 0;
        mdat_counter ++;  
      }
      checker = checker.slice(2);
    }
  }
    //This is where the data will be sliced, grouped into their respective segments and sent to the connected clients.
  if (processing_counter_queue.length > 0) {
    var jobs_removal_counter = 0;
    processing_counter_queue.forEach(job_info => {
      if (job_info.box_type == 'ftyp&moov' && buf_chunks_string_holder_array.length >= job_info.end_index) {
        initialization_segment_to_send = buf_chunks_string_holder_array.slice(0, job_info.end_index);
        initialization_segment_ready_flag = true;
        buf_chunks_string_holder_array = buf_chunks_string_holder_array.slice(job_info.end_index);
        jobs_removal_counter++;
      }
      if (job_info.box_type == 'moof&mdat' && buf_chunks_string_holder_array.length >= job_info.end_index) {
        buffered_media_segment_to_send = buf_chunks_string_holder_array.slice(0, job_info.end_index);
        buffered_media_segment_ready_flag = true;
        buf_chunks_string_holder_array = buf_chunks_string_holder_array.slice(job_info.end_index);
        if (buf_chunks_string_holder_array.length!= 0 ||
          (buf_chunks_string_holder_array[4]!= 102 && buf_chunks_string_holder_array[5]!= 116 && buf_chunks_string_holder_array[6]!= 121 && buf_chunks_string_holder_array[7]!= 112) || 
          (buf_chunks_string_holder_array[4]!= 109 && buf_chunks_string_holder_array[5]!= 100 && buf_chunks_string_holder_array[6]!= 97 && buf_chunks_string_holder_array[7]!= 116)){
          buf_chunks_string_holder_array = [];
          processing_counter_queue = [];
        }
        jobs_removal_counter++;
        if (wss.clients.size >= 1) {
          wss.clients.forEach(client => {
            client.send(new Uint8Array(buffered_media_segment_to_send).buffer);
          })
        }
      } 
      processing_counter_queue = processing_counter_queue.slice(jobs_removal_counter);
    }
    );
  }
});

ffmpeg.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`stderr: ${data}`);
});

ffmpeg.on('close', (code) => {
  console.log(`FFmpeg process exited with code ${code}`);
});
```